# Dynamic Way to Check for Broken Image ALT tags on Site?

Tags: html

Is there a website generator that can search for a given URL and output the urls where the images are missing their ALT tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - use the [w3c markup validator](http://validator.w3.org/).  It will output an error for `<img>` tags that do not have the required `alt` attribute.

Note that this will only happen for doctypes which require the alt attribute. I believe that, at minimum, all XHTML doctypes require it, so if your page does not already have that doctype, you might consider adding it temporarily to use the validator.

Comment: This won't check for empty `alt` tags only missing ones. As an empty `alt` tag is a valid tag.

Answer (score 2):

[Why don't you use W3C Validator?](http://validator.w3.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 sites

http://www.web-backlinks.com/webpageimgaltchecker.asp - seems to only do alt's

http://www.clarity-media.co.uk/alttagchecker.php - seems to only do alt tags.

As people mentioned you can use w3c validator but then you got to filter through all the other invalid ones and if your really only looking for imgs this might same you a bit of time.